# Why can't the server find the requested page on a WordPress website?

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I migrated my website from one host service provider to another, and whenever I load my website, only the homepage is accessible, other pages are returning:

```
404 Not Found
Please forward this error screen to (domainname.io)'s WebMaster.
The server cannot find the requested page:


domainname.io/cp_errordocument.shtml (port 443)
```

What could be wrong?